An irreducible topological space is compact
We call $X$ irreducible if $X$ is non-empty and $X$ cannot be written as a union of proper closed subsets of $X$. I feel that it should be easy to prove that $X$ is compact but I don't know how. I tried to take any open cover of $X$ and do it by contradiction so any finite union of elements of the cover is a proper subset of $X$ but I don't know how to conclude from here, any help would be appreciated.

$\Bbb R$ with the cocountable topology is irreducible and not compact.

Here is a counterexample. Take the natural numbers $\mathbb N = \{1,2,3,4,\ldots\}$ with the topology whose nonempty, proper open sets are the finite initial segments $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, for arbitrary $n \in \mathbb N$.
There is no proper closed subset containing $1$.
And the collection of proper open subsets covers $\mathbb N$, but no finite subcollection covers $\mathbb N$.

In addition to Lee Mosher's answer, in $\pi$-Base you can find more examples of irreducible topological spaces that aren't compact (see here).
Notice that the particular point topology on an uncountable set $X$ (let $p \in X$ be the particular point; $A \subseteq X$ is open if $A = \emptyset$, or if $p \in A$) is irreducible (the particular point is in every non-empty open set), and it isn't even Lindelöf (if $p \in X$ is the particular point, then $\{\{x, p\} : x \in X\}$ is an open cover of $X$ that doesn't admit a countable subcover).
You can browse for more examples of spaces verifying certain properties by typing the properties in the "Filter by Formula" text box.
